# StreamAPI vs ModelDerivative API for Forge Viewer - 10x difference in load time?

Tags: autodesk-forge

We recently started using the streamAPI and SVF2 instead of SVF1 and model derivative for the viewer. But have experienced a massive increase in load time after this update.

Chrome load time in seconds, initial load time / load time on refresh (after certain parts are cached):

EU

Stream 25.0 / 2.6

Derivative 4.0 / 2.1

Firefox load time in seconds, initial load time / load time on refresh (after certain parts are cached):

EU

Stream 67.0 / 3.6

Derivative 7.8 / 2.7

US

Stream 108.2 / 3.8

Derivative 10.1 / 3.3

Is the StreamAPI that much slower or is there a degradation of services right now? Also, any reason for Firefox having a 2x worse performance?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds really strange. SVF2 typically provides significant decrease in file size (due to some sophisticated geometry deduplication), and it also uses WebSockets to transfer the chunks to the client that typically improves the loading times as well.

Could you check the Network tab in your browser and see if WebSockets are used? And what version of Forge Viewer are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! After further research it happens on some of our developers computers, but not all. Attempting to look closer into it. Quite reproduceable though, very slow on new M1 Macs with latest version of Chrome. Looking for same behaviour in ACC.

Comment: Sending you the relevant IFC on email. But this seem to be a problem for all newly uploaded models for us.